# How to subset a data frame based on values in another data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame that contains time series observations on several individuals (identified by `ID`). It is structured like this:

````r
>data
ID   time   Var1   Var2   Var3
a     1      …      …      …
a     2      …      …      …
a     3      …      …      …
a     4      …      …      …
… 
b     1      …      …      …
b     1      …      …      …
b     1      …      …      …
b     1      …      …      …
… 
I have another data frame `timedata` that contains one row for each `ID`, it is structured like this:
```r
>timedata
ID  time
a   200
b   250
c   278
…    …
````

For each individual, I want to subset the value in the first data set `data` where `time` equals the time specified in the second data set `timedata`. I would normally use this:

```r
data2 <- 
  map2_df(timedata$ID, timedata$time, ~ 
            data%>%
            filter(ID == .x, time == .y))
```

However, my real `times` have decimals, and due to differences of recorders the decimals in each data set are not the same (but the numbers before the decimal place are). How can I change this code from: `time` in `data` "equals" `time` to say: `time` in `data` "contains (the numbers before the decimal)" `time`, without rounding both data sets to a whole number?

Comment: how about joining the tables and then filtering ? it would be much faster approach as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to verify without actual data. But here goes:

```
data %>%
  mutate(timeR=round(time)) %>%
  semi_join(
          mutate(timedata, timeR=round(time)),
    by=c("ID", "timeR")) %>%
  select(-timeR)
```